# Need some help trying to design a NextJS app architecture

Tags: reactjs, next.js, architecture, domain-driven-design

I'm new to React and NextJS, so I have a couple of doubts about how to define a proper architecture so I can move on with the development of my app.

This is what I have right now:

1. `@models`: stores a `<entity | non-entity>.model.ts` file for each entity or non-entity concept of my app. Each file will typically have an interface defined for the entity and most of them will also have some related DTOs. So `customer.model.ts` has the following interfaces defined inside of it: `Customer` and `CustomerCreateDTO`.
2. `@repositories`: each entity has a related `@repositories/<entity>` folder, in which I'll have a file that defines the repository interface and then other files that implement that interface. So in `@repositories/customers` I have the following files: `customers.repository.ts` and `customers-api.repository.ts`.  The last one implements the methods defined in the first one by simply send and receiving HTTP requests to my Rest API. I could probably also have something like `customers-local.repository.ts` that could use a local file as a mockup database. All generic repositories definition actually extends a common `Repository` interface, whoch defines `find*()`like mehtods to be implemented.
3. `@services`: each entity also has a `@services/<entity>` folder, in which I also kind of define a common interface in `@services/customers/customers.service.ts`. This interface is actually extended from a common `EntityService`, which defines common methods like `findById`, `findAll`, `create`, ...
4. `@contexts`: here I create a couple of contexts so I can store data and access it throughout all componentes of my app. I currently have only two contexts: `AppContext` (isLoading and some other app related attributes) and `AuthContext` (isSignedIn?, user object, ...).
5. `@hooks`: each entity will also have a `@hooks/use-<entity>.ts` file that defines a `use<Entity>` Rect hook. This hook will instantiate the entities services, often injecting some dependencies and will call methods from the services returning the results.
6. `@pages`: here is where I want to use all of this.

So, in order to list the customers I have something like this:

```
@pages/customers.ts -> @hooks/use-customer.hook:findAll() -> @services/customers/customers-api.service:findAll() -> @repositories/customers/customers-api.repository.findAll()
```

Here are some rules I'd like to check with you guys. Any thought on those will be much appreciated.

1. Every entity will demand a model, a repository (definition+implementation), a service (definition+implementation), a hook and a page
2. The page should only use the hook and sometimes the contexts, if it wants to check global values
3. The hook only returns methods or state that is defined in itself, it does not re-export contexts attributes (for example, the `useAuth` hook only exports the `signIn`, `singOut` methods, the page will have to acces the `AuthContext` to keep track on `isAuthenticated`, `user`, and so on
4. If the service that is being called through the hook changes a context, the page will have to access the context itself in order to get the new values. I mean, I will not re-export the contexts' attributes through the hook

So I guess my problem is to understand and define the responsabilities of the hooks X contexts X services X repositories components. I guess I could make it work in many ways, but I'd like to clearly define each layer responsability... And I want to be sure that I do need/want all those layers.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank's!